# Use AWS Load Balancer several times

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Currently we have a loadbalancer where a listener listens on https and then escorts to a target group where our ec2 windows instance is the target.

Now we have another ec2 instance (linux). The should be accessible via another subdomain. Do I need a new load balancer (which costs money..) or can I use one and split the targets somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify which type of Load Balancer you are using? If you are using ALB (application load balancer) you can configure "Host conditions" to route to different domains.

Based on [AWS ALB documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#listener-rules):

> You can use host conditions to define rules that forward requests to different target groups based on the host name in the host header (also known as host-based routing). This enables you to support multiple domains using a single load balancer.

If you are using classic ELB, you need different load balancers to support different domains.

Comment: Where can i check if our load balancer is a ALB or ELB?

Comment: @Hendouz hope you got the answer. Good luck!